# Google Spreadsheets Row Insert Reference Updating Behavior

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with one column and two rows:

```
cell A1: 2
cell A2: =A1 (displays as "2" because of the reference to A1)
```

If I insert a row between these two rows (by right-clicking on row 2, and selecting "insert 1 row above"), a blank row is inserted such that I now have no value in cell A2.  But in cell A3, I still have the value "2", and the formula of cell A3 is still "=A1".

Is there a way to make the formula in A3 point to the value of the newly inserted row ("=A2"), similar to the default behavior in Excel?  I'm finding it extremely tedious to have to go and adjust all the references each time I insert a row somewhere in the middle of my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=OFFSET(A2,-1,)` should also work.

Answer (score 3):

After some poking around, I found what appears to be the answer:

```
INDIRECT("A" + ROW()-1)
```

yields the value of the row above, and maintains this even if I insert a row.  This is the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as _Accepted_.